# MVC ViewData Model null after Post-back to Controller Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple **MVC 4 (Beta)** Application and just observed something that I assume may be handled differently. In this case, when the below Product Action is called a Model is created and assigned to **ViewData** for use in the **View**. This all works fine, the **Model** property is not-null, and the Views use of the Model property works.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product()
{
    return ExecuteFormRequest(View(), true, delegate
    {
        var model = Request.ParseFromQueryString<Product>();

        if (model != null)
        {
            ViewData.Model = model;
        }

        return View();
    });
}
```

When the Product is updated and Post'ed back to the Controller all the data looks fine, but if the product fails validation and I return the View ActionResult (*as shown below*) the **View** encounters a null reference exception because the Views **Model** property is now null

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Product(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Do other business stuff and target new or same View    

    return View();
}
```

This is the line in the **View** that leads to a null reference exception, because the **Model** Property is now null.

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.MyValue)) {}
```

The way I resolved this was to reset the **Model** Property (*as shown below*). This seems wrong to me and I'm wondering if I'm approaching this all wrong. Any ideas welcome?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Product(Product product)
{
    if (product!= null)
    {
        ViewData.Model = product;
    }

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Do other business stuff and target new or same View    

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a strongly typed viewmodel, why are you using viewdata? try this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product()
{
    return ExecuteFormRequest(View(), true, delegate
    {
        var model = Request.ParseFromQueryString<Product>();

        //if (model != null)
        //{
        //    ViewData.Model = model;
        //}

        //return View();
        return View(model);
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Product(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //return View();
        return View(product);
    }

    // Do other business stuff and target new or same View    

    //return View();
    return View(product);
}
```

The reason you are seeing the behavior with your approach is because HTTP is stateless. Unlike webforms, MVC does not reconstitute all of your variables after a post. Each action method starts out with a new ViewData dictionary.

Comment: So... Yes, I'm approaching this all wrong. This is a good example of learning through failure. That fixed it, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Where do you get "ExecuteFormRequest" method from? I tried searching it on google to find the correct library to reference but am not pulling a single hit.

Comment: @Adrian, `ExecuteFormRequest` was from the OP. It must be a custom method that @JoeGeeky created.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using ViewData? Don't use it. Make it simple and always pass your view model to the view when returning it:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Product()
{
    return ExecuteFormRequest(View(), true, delegate
    {
        var model = Request.ParseFromQueryString<Product>();

        return View(model);
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Product(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(product);
    }

    // Do other business stuff and target new or same View    

    return View(product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If You are using Action Link in the View to go for Post Back Action. The form is not being submitted which results with model of null values. try to submit the form on action link Click event that will resolve the Issue.

Here is a sample to Submit the form on Action Link event

```
@Html.ActionLink("Save1", "Method1", "HelloWorld", @Model, new { onclick = "$(this).parents('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href'));$(this).parents('form').submit();return false;" });
```